# "do you want to allow this request" screen in Android, google accounts

Tags: android, google-account

Once allowed, the android built-in "Access request" screen never shows up again. Development is hard this way. How can I make it show again (same account same appliccation - I want it to ask for access again and again) ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you accessing some google services from Android? or are you talking about your app permission.

Comment: It is the first case - accessing google services

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using Oauth2.0. ? The solution is based on the type of mechanism. The basic idea is to invalidate the access token ( that you get at the end of Oauth dance), but how to invalidate is a function of the mechanism.

Comment: Yes, that would suffice. accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(account.type, authToken); will do just fine. Why don't you make it official ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to invalidate the access token. To invalidate the access token you can use the a[ccount Manager.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)